# How do I write "Thousand Hearts" in French?

Tags: adjectifs, nombres, noms

I consider using it as sort of a "brand-name", so it needs to have an "adjective feel". Such as "Thousand Hearts Films" (instead of "a thousand hearts films").
Google Translate gives "mille coeurs", but searching through the web I found "à mille cœurs", can I drop the "à" like I did on the English version? Is "cœurs" better than "coeurs"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes "Mille Cœurs" is the literal translation for "Thousand Hearts". And yes, you can drop the "à" given by Google Translate, which adds nothing to your "brand-name". The "à" would be used to link the thousand hearts to their subject.

For instance:
a thousand hearts flower => une fleur à mille cœurs

In your case, if it's a "brand name", then "Films Mille Cœurs" is perfect (as opposed to "Films à Mille Cœurs"), but you loose your "adjective feel". "Mille Cœurs" is not an adjective of "Films", it's a proper noun. If you need this "adjective feel", then "à" is mandatory, but it looks like you loose your "brand-name" feel.

On the last point: "cœurs" is indeed better than "coeurs", because "coeurs" is not correct (it's a typo). The only and right way to write it is "cœurs".

Comment: Good answer (+1). Only remark to add : your proposition of **Films Mille Cœurs** may be "perfect" on the meaning aspect, but is unfortunately a mess to pronounce. A chance that the original brand name was not *Thousand Bloodhounds Films*... (Films Mille Limiers ?)

Answer (score 2):

May i propose:
Mille et un Cœurs

In french we often add "et un" for expressing a multiplicity factors that shouldn't be literally interpreted as exactly 1000. (i.e. When you wish to say "A Lot !" )

Just like the *One Thousand and One Nights Tales* which in french becomes:
*Comptes des "mille et une" Nuits !*

Perhaps better for your intended usage.

Comment: Nice suggestion. However I will point out that "One Thousand and One" is already 1001 (mille et un). The French version didn't add an extra night to the tales.